# How define, what form called current Form in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How to define which form is the current Form in C#?
don't use parameters of construction and attribute like as parent form

Comment: hah? can you explain more your question ?

Comment: Please, post your question with a Descriptive meaning. What do you want actually?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a constructor that will allow to pass the calling form. For example:

```
public class Form2: Form
{
    private readonly Form _callingForm;
    public Form2(Form callingForm)
    {
        _callingForm = callingForm; 
    }

    ...
}
```

and then in the calling form:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Other than that there might be some forms like the main form for example which are not called from other form.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can define public property in child form, for example called `parent`, and show child using

```
ChildForm form = new ChildForm();

form.parent=this;

form.Show();
```